# Determine if an image is of "blank" paper

Tags: php, image, image-recognition, graphicsmagick

We are making a tool that will allow a chain of photos to be taken. Mixed in with real photos will be photos of blank sheets of paper.  I want to separate the series of photos by identifying the images of blank pages.

I'm trying to find a way to identify the blank sheet. Either by counting colors, or some other method. Maybe filesize?

I've got GraphicsMagick, so maybe there's something useful there, and the code will be in PHP, but could be in anything if it works well.

Comment: I found out `gm identify IMG_0551.JPG -format %k` which gives me < 10k for the blank image and > 100k for normal images. Any issues with that?

Comment: Good question Sean! When I first read it, it wasn't very clear what you were trying to achieve so I restructured your explanation a bit. It is perfectly okay (and encouraged) for you to answer your own question, so why don't you post your comment as an answer to your own question.

Comment: I'm vaguely uneasy about the suggested method... any chance you can post your shot of a blank piece of paper please, and maybe one of your other shots so I can experiment with realistic images?

Comment: See zip file http://cl.ly/1A2C1P2s0T2u.  So far this has worked 100% for about 25 photos.

Answer (score 1):

You may do fine with the number of colours, but I am somewhat uneasy about that working well - though it is hard to say without more sample images. So if you run into difficulties with that, you might like to look at the histograms of the two items - *paper* and *"not paper"*.

**Paper**

[image]

**Not Paper**

[image]

You can see that the paper histogram has very steep sides and no tails, whereas the *"not paper"* histogram has fatter tails. The kurtosis of the image is a measure of exactly that - the fatness of the tails. Higher kurtosis means more of the variance in the image is the result of infrequent extreme deviations, as opposed to frequent modestly sized deviations. So you would expect the *"not paper"* to have a higher kurtosis because it has *"lumps"* of other stuff in the image rather than the fairly uniform paper.

If you get ImageMagick to report the kurtosis of the two images you can see the marked difference.

```
identify -verbose notpaper.jpg | grep -E "kurtosis:|Red:|Green:|Blue:|Overall"
    Red:
      kurtosis: 1.03434
    Green:
      kurtosis: 1.22576
    Blue:
      kurtosis: 0.593927
    Overall:
      kurtosis: 1.49035
```

And for the paper...

```
identify -verbose paper.jpg | grep -E "kurtosis:|Red:|Green:|Blue:|Overall"
    Red:
      kurtosis: -0.953723
    Green:
      kurtosis: -0.980636
    Blue:
      kurtosis: -1.06634
    Overall:
      kurtosis: -0.0151458
```

As I said, you may do fine with the number of colours, but maybe consider this if you run into problems.

Comment: This is brilliant. I may give this a shot and do an experiment to see if either fails and at what error rate.

Comment: gm identify -verbose IMG_0615.JPG | grep -E "kurtosis:|Red:|Green:|Blue:|Overall"
    Red:      8 bits
    Green:    8 bits
    Blue:     8 bits
    Red:
    Green:
    Blue:

Comment: It looks as though GraphicsMagick doesn't report kurtosis - just ImageMagick.

Answer (score 0):

try to use `imagecolorat` refrence [Here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolorat.php)

```
<?php
$im = imagecreatefrompng("php.png");
$rgb = imagecolorat($im, 10, 15);
$r = ($rgb >> 16) & 0xFF;
$g = ($rgb >> 8) & 0xFF;
$b = $rgb & 0xFF;

var_dump($r, $g, $b);
?>
```

or this

```
<?php
$im = imagecreatefrompng("php.png");
$rgb = imagecolorat($im, 10, 15);

$colors = imagecolorsforindex($im, $rgb);

var_dump($colors);
?>
```

this will o/p like this

```
array(4) {
  ["red"]=>
  int(119)
  ["green"]=>
  int(123)
  ["blue"]=>
  int(180)
  ["alpha"]=>
  int(127)
}
```

check for white value and compare .If all the values are 255, 255,255 then this is white paper.

Comment: The issue with this is that nothing is pure white.  So it would never actually be 255

Comment: you can take an approximate value. Something like color less than 260 like this

Answer (score 0):

`gm identify IMG_0551.JPG -format %k` anything <10k is most likely a blank sheet.